# Testing logging output with pytest

Tags: python, logging, pytest, python-logging

I am trying to write a test, using pytest, that would check that a specific function is writing out a warning to the log when needed. For example:

In module.py:

```
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def run_function():
    if something_bad_happens:
        LOGGER.warning('Something bad happened!')
```

In test_module.py:

```
import logging
from module import run_function

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_func():
    LOGGER.info('Testing now.')
    run_function()
    ~ somehow get the stdout/log of run_function() ~
    assert 'Something bad happened!' in output
```

I have seen that you can supposedly get the log or the stdout/stderr with pytest by passing `capsys` or `caplog` as an argument to the test, and then using either `capsus.readouterr()` or `caplog.records` to access the output.

However, when I try those methods, I only see "Testing now.", and not "Something bad happened!". It seems like the logging output that is happening within the call to `run_function()` is not accessible from `test_func()`?

The same thing happens if I try a more direct method, such as `sys.stdout.getvalue()`. Which is confusing, because `run_function()` is writing to the terminal, so I would think that would be accessible from `stdout`...?

Basically, does anyone know how I can access that 'Something bad happened!' from within `test_func()`?

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/logging.html

Answer (score 73):

I don't know why this didn't work when I tried it before, but this solution works for me now:

In test_module.py:

```
import logging
from module import run_function

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_func(caplog):
    LOGGER.info('Testing now.')
    run_function()
    assert 'Something bad happened!' in caplog.text
```

Comment: I think it might work for Python 3.5, but not 3.6 or 3.7.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you're trying but I'm using python3.7 and my caplog.text contained what I expected it to contain.

Comment: I am doing nearly the same thing and it is not working - meaning that `caplog.text` is empty.  The only difference is that `run_function()` is method in a `pytest.fixture` in my case, but that shouldnt matter, right?

Comment: @exic It's not working for me.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59875983/974555).

Comment: As mentioned correctly in @ssoler's answer , in your logger setup, make sure is logger.propagate=True

Comment: What if my `run_function()` takes an argument `record`? How should I pass the record? @lauren.marietta

Answer (score 69):

`test_module.py` should look like this:

```
import logging
from module import run_function

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_func(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.WARNING):
        run_function()
    assert 'Something bad happened!' in caplog.text
```

or, alternatively:

```
import logging
from module import run_function

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_func(caplog):
    caplog.set_level(logging.WARNING)
    run_function()
    assert 'Something bad happened!' in caplog.text
```

Documentation for pytest capture logging is [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/logging.html#caplog-fixture)

Comment: As mentioned correctly in @ssoler's answer , in your logger setup, make sure is logger.propagate=True

Answer (score 10):

In your logging set up, check `propagate` is set to True, otherwise caplog handler is not able to see the logging message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just explicitly mentioned the name of the module instead of **name** inside the test function And set the propagate attribute to True.

Note: module should be the directory in which you have scripts to be test.

```
def test_func():

    LOGGER = logging.getLogger("module")
    LOGGER.propagate = True
    run_function()
    ~ somehow get the stdout/log of run_function() ~
    assert 'Something bad happened!' in output
```