# Why is caplog.text empty, even though the function I'm testing is logging?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, logging, pytest

I'm trying to use pytest to test if my function is logging the expected text, such as addressed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53125305/974555) (the pyunit equivalent would be [assertLogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs)).  Following the [pytest logging documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/logging.html#caplog-fixture), I am passing the `caplog` fixture to the tester.  The documentation states:

> Lastly all the logs sent to the logger during the test run are made available on the fixture in the form of both the logging.LogRecord instances and the final log text.

The module I'm testing is:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def foo():
    logger.info("Quinoa")
```

The tester is:

```py
def test_foo(caplog):
    from mwe16 import foo
    foo()
    assert "Quinoa" in caplog.text
```

I would expect this test to pass.  However, running the test with `pytest test_mwe16.py` shows a test failure due to `caplog.text` being empty:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.3.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /tmp
plugins: mock-1.12.1, cov-2.8.1
collected 1 item

test_mwe16.py F                                                          [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ test_foo ___________________________________

caplog = <_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture object at 0x7fa86853e8d0>

    def test_foo(caplog):
        from mwe16 import foo
        foo()
>       assert "Quinoa" in caplog.text
E       AssertionError: assert 'Quinoa' in ''
E        +  where '' = <_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture object at 0x7fa86853e8d0>.text

test_mwe16.py:4: AssertionError
============================== 1 failed in 0.06s ===============================
```

Why is `caplog.text` empty despite `foo()` sending text to a logger?  How do I use `pytest` such that `caplog.text` does capture the logged text, or otherwise verify that the text is being logged?

Comment: You logging could be: no configured, at wrong log level, filtered or not handled.

Comment: @KlausD. Isn't pytest supposed to take care of that? I thought pytest would add the necessary handlers to test the logging. From the documentation: "all the logs sent to the logger during the test run are made available on the fixture". Nothing about configuration or log levels there; but perhaps the documentation is unclear.

Comment: Although `pytest` adds a custom handler to capture the log records, it doesn't change the root logger level (which is set to `WARNING` by default). It thus doesn't get access to the records because they aren't propagated: `foo()` sends the info record to the logger, but it doesn't pass it to any handlers, including `caplog`'s one. If you want to turn on capturing, set `logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` in e.g. a session-scoped fixture.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The documentation is unclear here.  From trial and error, and notwithstanding the "all the logs sent to the logger during the test run are made available" text, it still only  captures logs with certain log levels.  To *actually* capture all logs, one needs to set the log level for captured log messages using [`caplog.set_level`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.LogCaptureFixture.set_level) or the [`caplog.at_level`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.LogCaptureFixture.at_level) context manager, so that the test module becomes:

```py
import logging
def test_foo(caplog):
    from mwe16 import foo
    with caplog.at_level(logging.DEBUG):
        foo()
    assert "Quinoa" in caplog.text
```

Now, the test passes:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.3.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /tmp
plugins: mock-1.12.1, cov-2.8.1
collected 1 item

test_mwe16.py .                                                          [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.04s ===============================
```

Answer (score 4):

In the logger set up, please set `logger.propagate=True`

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of Pytest, cf. the [feature request](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3697). I've resorted to creating a fixture based on `_pytest.logging.LogCaptureFixture` with a context manager and using it instead of `caplog`.

Some code:

```
from _pytest.logging import LogCaptureHandler, _remove_ansi_escape_sequences


class CatchLogFixture:
"""Fixture to capture logs regardless of the Propagate flag. See
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3697 for details.
"""

    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        return _remove_ansi_escape_sequences(self.handler.stream.getvalue())

    @contextmanager
    def catch_logs(self, level: int, logger: logging.Logger) -> LogCaptureHandler:
        """Set the level for capturing of logs. After the end of the 'with' statement,
        the level is restored to its original value.
        """
        self.handler = LogCaptureHandler()
        orig_level = logger.level
        logger.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(self.handler)
        try:
            yield self
        finally:
            logger.setLevel(orig_level)
            logger.removeHandler(self.handler)


@pytest.fixture
def capture_log():
    return CatchLogFixture().catch_logs
```

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet showing how you did this?