# Catch SystemExit message with Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, systemexit

I am writing test using pytest. I have a case where some function throws `SystemExit` with some error message on terminal in case of wrong input.

I want to write test for the case when `SystemExit` is thrown and verify that there is specific string in the output error message.

Here's the code:

```py
def test_validate_input():
  ...
  with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as error:
    _validate_function(test_wrong_input)
  assert error.value.code == 1
```

I am not able to get the output error message in `error` that I get on command line if I run the actual function the validate some input. Please let me know what I am missing here.

Edit:

I was calling a `subprocess.call_output` to run a command which was throwing the error. I have to add `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` in the `call_output` call as an argument to get the error message. Then I used @p3j4p5's answer in my test.

Comment: If that is indeed a message generated by logger you will want to look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125305/testing-logging-output-with-pytest).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I replaced the `log` with error message on terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pytest's [`raises()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.raises) takes a `match` argument. The docs tell us:

> If specified, a string containing a regular expression, or a regular expression object, that is tested against the string representation of the exception

and

> This is only used when `pytest.raises` is used as a context manager

So it should be suitable for your case:

```py
def test_validate_input():
  ...
  with pytest.raises(SystemExit, match='exception message content'):
      _validate_function(test_wrong_input)
```

This test will pass if the raised `SystemExit` exception has been raised with a message matching the provided regular expression, and will fail otherwise.

**Alternatively**, if you want to manually check the message:

> The context manager produces an `ExceptionInfo` object which can be used to inspect the details of the captured exception

In your case, assuming that `SystemExit` is called with and integer (code) and a string (message) that would be:

```py
def test_validate_input():
  ...
  with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as exc_info:
      _validate_function(test_wrong_input)

  assert exc_info.value.args[0] == 1
  assert exc_info.value.args[1] == 'exception message content'
```

Comment: I want to go for the manual check way, still I am not able to get the terminal output in `exc_info.value.args[1]`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had to add `stderror=subprocess.STDOUT` to get the error message.

Comment: That's great! Could you share with us where you added that statement?

Comment: Yes, I added as an edit in the answer, what I added.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your message is printed on stderr *before* `SystemExit` is raised, in this case you'll need [capsys](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#capsys)

```py
def test_validate_input(capsys):
  ...
  with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as error:
      _validate_function(test_wrong_input)
  assert error.value.code == 1
  captured = capsys.readouterr()
  assert captured.err == "Expected error message\n"
```

Comment: I tried with `capsys` but I am not getting anything in `captured.err` or `.out`

Comment: So, is the message is probably in the SystemExit exception, see other answer.